# Auto New Line In GD Library

Tags: php, gd

I'm using the GD Library to create images from data I'm pulling from an API.

The strings that are returned can sometimes be kind of lengthy, and I'm hoping to find a way to automatically create a new line for text if the string goes too far.

Is there something like this built into the GD library, or will I have to write some code to count the characters and move everything to a new line if it goes too long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GD is strictly for drawing. You'll need a text layout engine such as [Pango](http://mgdm.net/weblog/using-pango-for-php-a-taster).

Comment: GD supports true type fonts by default, to state that it's "purely for drawing" is very inaccurate. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php

Answer (score 0):

I am not familier with a built-in function that automatically creates new lines,
so I guess you need to write a php function that sorts the string to "sub-strings" 
according to your width length and then use them in your image.

Consider looking at this post:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagestring.php#90481