# suggestions for php classes to add text on image

Tags: php

I'm looking for a php class that can help me add text to an image.

I would like to define an x and y point for the upper left corner, and then set a width (maybe height) and then get the text in there so that it automatically continues on the next line. I've been searching but I can't figure out how to do this....

Comment: try searching http://www.phpclasses.org/

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using the GD library really easily. A tutorial is available right [here](http://blog.doh.ms/2008/02/12/adding-text-to-images-in-real-time-with-php/).

Comment: I don't see where it will continue on the next line?

Comment: GD is a drawing library, so I don't think it's gonna be doable at all. You can refer to this post for the automagic line break issue.(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639693/auto-new-line-in-gd-library)

Answer (score -1):

I've done something similar a few years back with using PHP and GD to create header graphics. It basically breaks the string of text into words, calculates the width of each word, and then adds each word one by one. If a word takes it over the width limit, it pushes that to the next line. With a bit of tweaking it should do the trick for you: http://www.ashleysheridan.co.uk/coding/php/PHP+Image+Header